# Cached template content not invalidating

Tags: templating, cache

My understanding of the {% cache %} tag is that if the content between it changes, the cache is invalidated and you see the new content.

I'm having an issue where a new entry is created in section, but it doesn't show up on the front-end unless I manually clear the cache in the control panel.

The content is pulled in via a loop such as:

```
{%  for entry in craft.entries.section( "news" ).limit(3) %}
```

Am I not understanding how this tag works or is something going wrong?

Edit: Here is the full code block wrapped by cache tags

```
{% cache %}
{%  for entry in craft.entries.section( item.nameId ).limit(3) %}
    <div class="cardRow_column-carousel">
        <a href="{{ entry.url }}" class="card" >
            <div class="card_imageHolder">
                <img class="card_image" src="{{ entry.tileImage.first().getUrl(cardCrop) }}">
            </div>
            <div class="card_content">
                <h4 class="card_content_heading">{{ entry.title }}</h4>
                <div class="card_content_icon">
                    {% if item.type == "video" %}
                        {% set iconType = "icon-video" %}
                    {% elseif item.type == "game" %}
                        {% set iconType = "icon-games" %}
                    {% elseif item.type == "image" or item.type == "imageGallery" %}
                        {% set iconType = "icon-image" %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% set iconType = "icon-paper" %}
                    {% endif %}
                    <i class="{{ iconType }} card_content_icon-category"></i>
                    <i class="icon-arrow-right card_content_icon_arrow"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endcache %}
```

The strange thing that I'm noticing is if I add an entry it never shows up, but if I delete one it does get cleared out. And deleting an entry then causes the new one to show up.

UPDATE: Craft support determined there was a bug and plans to fix it in the next version. Current version is Craft 2.1 build 2563.

Comment: I've had the same issue as well, basically had to turn off all caching for now until I find a fix

Comment: is the cache tag that wraps this line in the same template?

Comment: Can you post the portion of the template that is using the cache tag?

Comment: I posted the full code block above with an additional note about observations deleting entries.

Answer (score 4):

When **new** elements are created, there’s no way for Craft to immediately know which template caches should be cleared. That’s where the *Delete Stale Template Caches* task comes in. It loops through all of your caches that included element queries, re-runs the queries, and checks to see if the new element is now included in the results.

There are two things to be aware of, though:

1. Your element query must happen *inside* the `{% cache %}` tag pair.

   ```
   bad:

   {% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').limit(3) %}
   {% cache %}
       {% for entry in entries %}
           ...
       {% endfor %}
   {% endcache %}

   good:

   {% cache %}
       {% set entries = craft.entries.section('news').limit(3) %}
       {% for entry in entries %}
           ...
       {% endfor %}
   {% endcache %}
   ```
2. The cache querying is not immediate. After saving the entry you will see a little progress bar in the CP header. You need to wait until that has completed before your caches will be cleared.

Comment: I edited my question and posted the code block which is wrapped in the cache tags.  I see the progress bar in the header when I save the entry. It completes pretty quickly and the entry still doesn't show up on the front-end, even if I wait for minutes. If I add an expiration time to the cache tag then I will see it show up.

Comment: In that case you might be running into a bug. Please send us a ticket from your dashboard, including your templates and DB backup.

Comment: @BrandonKelly We are experiencing this same issue currently on a site.  Was this confirmed to be a bug? We are running Craft Pro 2.3.2640.

Comment: @aran Sorry for the late reply. If you're still experiencing an issue, please contact support@buildwithcraft.com.

Comment: Sorry for digging this up. I am having a similar situation where the new entry gets created from a front end form. So the _Delete Stale Template Caches_ task won’t get fired (I assume). I can trigger it by moving to the cp and hit reload or navigate around. 

Is there a way to trigger that task from the front end on entry creation?